# Unable to run app in Simulator : Xcode 6.0.1 iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I updated my Xcode to 6.0.1 from the App Store update notification
in the morning in the os X 10.9.5, and then restarted my mac.

Then i found the Xcode has been updated to the 6.0.1 ,But when i tried
to run my app on it i am getting only iOS device as the device,not
simulators.

in my simulator menu manage devices  there is no simulators only my
mac is present ,then i tried to add simulators but it has given me
error of path is not found,i tried every solutions found in the web
search like locations tab command line tools,everything is fine,

But still i am not getting the simulators?Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: I cannot even get Xcode 6.0.1 to run under 10.9.4.  Trying using the version downloaded from the Developer Download site and then I'll look into updating to 10.9.5.

Comment: No joy doing those things.  Xcode 6 is a disaster on my MacBook Pro (10.9), but is fine on my iMac (10.10).  FFS.

Answer (score 18):

Might be that resolve by tap `Xcode6--> Window--> Device` like following image:

[image]

When you select Device Option you get following window open:

[image]

There is appear all simulator or connected devices. If you found No simulator you can add by click on **+** Button then you get following window create simulator.

[image]

click an option there is simulator list and you get simulator. Hope that solve you issue.

Comment: i did this i am not able to add,i am getting an error like unable to determine device,But when i copied the core simulator and Xcode folders to the Developer folder in library its solved,now all simulators are showing ,i dont know why it is happening

Comment: might be that is some path issue of that take some old path of fonder any way at the end that solve :)

Answer (score 0):

Choose Preview > iOS Simulator Version > iOS 6.0 or 6.1.*
Choose Preview > Preview in iOS Simulator.

- If you don't see iOS 6.0 or iOS 6.1, see Downloading and Installing Xcode Components in the iOS Developer Library.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Have you read the question correctly and read that they are getting `"error of path is not found"` so the issue seems to be that on installing xcode has become corrupted possibly

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list'?
Is there anything interesting in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log to indicate a problem?
Are you able to add and delete simulator devices from the device manager?
Can you add and delete devices from the command line 'xcrun simctl create ...'?

Comment: when i try to add the simulators in manage devices it will thrown an error as "unable to determine device",but Xcode 5 works fine with all simulators

Comment: Xcode 5 does not contain CoreSimulator.  Xcode 6 and later use CoreSimulator with the old UI glued on top of the new foundation.  Check ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for more information on your errors.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can suggest is checking xcode-select from a Terminal. Type **xcode-select -p** and look at the output. This should be the Contents/Developer directory within your Xcode application. On my machine - because I don't leave Xcode in the Application folder, it reads */Applications/Developer/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/*. Make sure it's actually pointing at where Xcode is installed. For example you may be putting Xcode in a directory other than the usual /Applications, while xcode-select is looking for the Xcode internals in a different place than where Xcode is. I've been caught out by this before now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]