# Xcode 6.2 not showing simulator devices in run destinations menu

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I have created a new iOS project; by default the deployment target is iOS 8.2, but I don't have the option to use the simulator. I went to the Xcode preferences, and I don't have the option to download the iOS 8.2 simulator. I'm using Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e).

If I tried to open the simulator via developer tools. I get this error:

[image]

I rename Xcode.app and rebooted my mac but didn't help.

I ran "xcrun simctl list" and I got this list:

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
Resizable iPhone (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone)
Resizable iPad (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 8.1 (8.1 - 12B411) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1)
iOS 8.2 (8.2 - 12D508) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-2)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 8.1 --
-- iOS 8.2 --
```

Any of you know why I don't have the option to run my project in the simulator?

Comment: An easy way to create (re-create) iOS simulators: [create new simulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928588/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-6-0-1-ios-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely experiencing the issue mentioned in [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html):

> Renaming Xcode.app after running any of the Xcode tools in that bundle
>   may cause iOS simulator to be no longer be available. Either rename
>   Xcode.app back to what it was when first launched or restart your Mac.
>   (16646772)

Additionally, it may be the case that you really don't have any devices configured (did you delete them?).  Look at the output of `xcrun simctl list` and try creating devices using `xcrun simctl create`.  Also take a look in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices.  Is there anything there?

Comment: I have add it the output of "xcrun simctl list"

Comment: Try creating new devices as I mentioned above.  What about ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices ... what's in there?

Comment: I check the directory ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices and is empty.

Comment: Great, then it looks like things are behaving correctly.  You deleted your simulator devices, and now there are none visible.  As mentioned earlier, go try creating new devices to replace the ones you deleted.

Comment: I getting this:  xcrun simctl create
Usage: simctl create <name> <device type id> <runtime id> .  Can you post the parameters for the installation I can not find a example

Comment: Puck a name you want.  Identifiers are listed in simctl list